Is there a way to refresh a data in table populated from google apps script with JS?
I want to refresh data in the table every 5 seconds.

The table in Google Sheet is updated a few times per hour.
If necessary the whole div can be refreshed.

I've tried refreshing the full page with:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
          setTimeout(function() {window.location.reload()}, 10000)
          google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(populateTable)
            .getNearlyTPT()
        });

But it gives me a a blank page.
The table looks like this :



Data 1
Data 2
Data 3




Task
16:30
done



Code in Code.gs:
function getNearlyTPT(){
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('xxx');
  let ws = ss.getSheetByName("xxx");
  const today = new Date();
  let h = today.getHours();
  let m = today.getMinutes();
  let data = ws.getRange('H3:J').getValues().filter(r => r[0] && r[1] > h +":"+m);
  return data
}

Code in <script>:
function makeRow(row) {
          let tr = document.createElement('tr');
          row.forEach(cell => {
            let td = document.createElement('td');
            td.textContent = cell;
            tr.appendChild(td)
          });
          return tr;
        }


        function populateTable(data) {
          let tasks = document.getElementById('tpt');
          data.forEach(row => {
            let tr = makeRow(row);
            tasks.appendChild(tr);
          });
        }

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
          google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(populateTable)
            .getNearlyTPT()
        });

And div in html:
<div id = "tpt2Table">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Data 1</th>
            <th>Data 2</th>
            <th>Data 3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tpt"></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>


You should leverage Google Apps Script's setInterval to call your getNearlyTPT function every 5 seconds, fetching updated data.
Update the existing table rows dynamically in your HTML using JavaScript's DOM manipulation.
HTML (modified):
<div id="tpt2Table">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Data 1</th>
        <th>Data 2</th>
        <th>Data 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tpt"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script>
  // Call getNearlyTPT initially to populate the table
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(populateTable)
    .getNearlyTPT();

  function populateTable(data) {
    let tableBody = document.getElementById('tpt');
    tableBody.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing rows

    data.forEach(row => {
      let tr = document.createElement('tr');
      row.forEach(cell => {
        let td = document.createElement('td');
        td.textContent = cell;
        tr.appendChild(td);
      });
      tableBody.appendChild(tr);
    });
  }

  // Refresh data every 5 seconds
  setInterval(function() {
    google.script.run.getNearlyTPT().then(populateTable);
  }, 5000);
</script>

The initial populateTable call using google.script.run fills the table with data.
The setInterval function triggers getNearlyTPT every 5 seconds using a promise (then) to handle the asynchronous response.
The updated data is passed to populateTable, which clears the existing table body (innerHTML = '') and rebuilds it with the new data.
